# Set vim's internal shell path

Tags: vim, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to configure the $PATH env variable of vim's internal shell.

I have commands that update the $PATH several times during a session. I see that vim inherits my shell's first $PATH - but not updated $PATH variables.

Some things that might be helpful:

- I open vim multiple times - with changes to $PATH in between
- The internal shell does source cshrc every time I launch the internal shell
- Sourcing cshrc on the main shell doesn't change $PATH

-- update
So the problem is because the .cshrc file. It does some initial setting up where the path gets reset. Launching a new shell within the current shell resets $PATH. I'll have to figure out a way to go around this.

I'm using tcsh on a redhat machine. Any clue why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: How do you start Vim – once per session, or every time?

Comment: Multiple times - with changes to $PATH in between (when vim is closed). Maybe vim's internal shell sources .cshrc/etc? Could that reset the $PATH everytime?

Comment: It could be that... `echo "starting cshrc"` is a good debugging tool, by the way.

Comment: Hmm - it does source cshrc. But I tried sourcing it in the actual shell. It doesn't change $PATH there.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want your internall shell to source `.cshrc`, try passing an option to it, by setting `shellcmdflag`, e.g.:

```
set shellcmdflag=--norc
```

This will only affect the shell when using `!` and `:!`. To affect also `:shell` use:

```
set shell=bash\ --norc
```

(of course replace that with your shell of choice and the correct option to skip reading the rc file).